# How do I reference a javascript variable in the "style" attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, inline-styles

I'm using Vue and GraphQL to generate a grid of `div`s based on rows in a database. Each row/`div` has a `background_color` column. I want users to be able to change the `background_color` of each div *separately* using a form inside that `div`.

I've verified that my forms are correctly updating the corresponding `background_color` column, however when I try to apply that value to the div, nothing happens:

```
<div v-for="row in graphQL_result.table" class="grid">
     <div class="box" style="background:row.background_color">
```

If I am not able to reference a database value in my style, how should I approach this instead?

Comment: check the :style directive in the vue3 documentation for full disclosure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try style binding:

```html
<div class="box" :style="{'background' : row.background_color}"></div>
```

For more [information](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles)